# I am not able to get any response from server while using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-intentservice

I am using volley to get the response from server with intent service but can not able get the response from server. Intent service is calling every time but response not getting from server.
Here is my code intent service with volley :-

```
public class SampleSchedulingService extends IntentService {

String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.125:8080/";
String REG_CHECK = BASE_URL + "" + "services/account/check";

/**
 * @param name
 */
public SampleSchedulingService() {
    super("MYSCHEDULINGSERVICE");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.IntentService#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "I ran!");
    updateLatLong();

    //SampleAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

/**
 * 
 */
private void updateLatLong() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("imeiNo", "myImeiNumber");

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), params.toString());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            VolleyHelper.POST, REG_CHECK,
            new JSONObject(params), onJsonObjectReqResponse(), null);
    ApplicationController.getInstance()
            .addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}

/**
 * @return
 */
private Response.Listener<JSONObject> onJsonObjectReqResponse() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), response.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }               
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: try e.printStackTrace() in catch block, if there is any exception post it.

Comment: @Harry no exception getting
Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), params.toString());
up to this point it is working but reponse only not getting.

Comment: Please add Response.ErrorListener to your JsonObjectRequest.

Comment: Thank you @IvanP now able to get what error i'm getting from server.